# How to bundle a VSCode Language Server extension with ESbuild into ONE FILE?

Tags: vscode-extensions, esbuild

Is there any way to bundle a VSCode Language Server Extension using ESbuild into ONE FILE?
The WebPack configuration is very hard and it is not working here.

The ESlint configuration is easy, and I do know how to configure it, but it results in 2 directories in my `dist` folder:

```
dist
  |-- client
  |     |-- src
  |           |-- extension.js
  |           |-- extension.js.map
  |-- server
  |     |-- src
  |           |-- server.js
  |           |-- server.js.map
```

I tried the following:

```json
"esbuild-base": "esbuild ./client/src/extension.ts ./server/src/server.ts --bundle --outdir=dist/ --external:vscode --format=cjs --platform=node",
```

The whole `scripts` object:

```json
"scripts": {
        "vscode:prepublish": "npm run esbuild-base -- --minify",
        "compile": "tsc -b",
        "watch": "tsc -b -w",
        "lint": "eslint ./client/src ./server/src --ext .ts,.tsx",
        "postinstall": "cd client && npm install && cd ../server && npm install && cd ..",
        "test": "sh ./scripts/e2e.sh",
        "esbuild-base": "esbuild ./client/src/extension.ts ./server/src/server.ts --bundle --outdir=dist/ --external:vscode --format=cjs --platform=node",
        "esbuild": "npm run esbuild-base -- --sourcemap",
        "esbuild-watch": "npm run esbuild-base -- --sourcemap --watch",
        "test-compile": "tsc -p ./"
    },
```

Answer (score 0):

I was running into the same problem. As far as I've been able to figure out, there's not a way to get it to build into one file. However, the way you have esbuild setup is correct (it should build two files so the language server can run as a separate process). What you have to do is make your `extension.ts` file point to `dist/server/src/server.js`.
In `extension.ts`:

```js
// From the language server docs: https://code.visualstudio.com/api/language-extensions/language-server-extension-guide
const serverModule = context.asAbsolutePath(join('dist', 'server', 'src', 'server.js'));
const serverOptions: ServerOptions = {
    run: { module: serverModule, transport: TransportKind.ipc },
    debug: {
        module: hbServerModule,
        transport: TransportKind.ipc,
        options: { execArgv: ['--nolazy', '--inspect=6009'] } // Allow debugging
    }
};
const clientOptions: LanguageClientOptions = { documentSelector: [{ scheme: 'file', language: '<lang id>' }] };
const client = new LanguageClient('<server id>', '<name>', serverOptions, clientOptions);
client.start();
```

vsce appears to warn about too many javascript files when there's a bunch, but when its only a few, its fine.

For anyone else struggling to figure out esbuild with the language server protocol who'd like a full example project, [here's my repository](https://github.com/CoolSpy3/hmmm-language-support/tree/v2.0.1) where I managed to get it working. (This link goes to a specific tag. The commits adding esbuild support should be the last ~5 before this tag.)